# How to give a class as valid parameter for printf where it returns as a string?

Tags: c++, class, parameters, printf

I have a class and I want that when I give it as a parameter for printf/sprintf that it is being used as a specific string (depending on whats going on in the class). Is something like that possible ?

```
printf("blah blah  %s  ", customclass);
```

What do I have to do that this happens without any kind of typecasting and without any kind of necessary function call like customclass.xyz() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` is a variadic function, which cannot be used in any sensible manner with user-defined types.

If you're in C++, you should prefer streams (e.g. `std::cout`) to `printf` for exactly this sort of reason.  With streams, you can overload the `<<` operator:

```
class CustomClass
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, CustomClass c)
{
    os << "{" << c.x << "," << c.y << "}";
    return os;
}

...

CustomClass customclass;
customclass.x = 5;
customclass.y = 7;
std::cout << customclass << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My problem is that I am working on a huge program and cannot change the thousands of printf and sprintf lines in it. Is there no way at all, to make printf and sprintf work with a custom class ?

Comment: @HardCoder: Then you don't have any choice but to write a `getString()` function...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
cout << "blah blah " << typeid(customclassobject OR customclass).name() << endl;
```

UPDATE: In case you want to print members of the class (something similar to toString() in Java, then Oli Charlesworth's answer is correct.