# How to properly overload printf to print a value from a class c++

Tags: c++, printf, overloading

Is there a way to use printf to print a value of a class?

```
class example
{
public:
    int x;
    example(int in) : x(in) {}
}

void printf(example object)
{
    printf(object.x);
}
```

Is there a way to do that correctly?
When I do that, I get a segmentation fault, 
But when I use "example& object", it says

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'object&' to an
>   rvalue of 'object'

And when I put "const example& object", it says

> Passing 'const example' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers

note:
I already did the std::cout (operator overloading <<) and it works, but I just want to try to use printf

I also tried making it do

```
std::cout<<object.x;
```

When I did that, it automatically added a newline at the front of the int (like this):

```
example a(5);
printf("the value is: %i", a) ;
```

Result:

```
the value is:
5
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626441/how-to-give-a-class-as-valid-parameter-for-printf-where-it-returns-as-a-string

Comment: Passing an `example` object as-is directly to `printf()` is **undefined behavior**. You need to pass its `x` member explicitly instead: `example a(5); printf("the value is: %d", a.x);` "*I just want to try to use printf*" - there is really no good reason to do that in C++. "*I also tried making it do `std::cout<<object.x;` When I did that, it automatically added a newline at the front of the int*" - no, it doesn't. A newline is printed only if you print an actual `\n` character or use `std::endl`. `operator<<` for an `int` value does neither of those.